# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project. It is ok when I run on Intellij IDE. I did'nt get any error. When I deploy to tomcat server it is running but when I try to connect database I am getting error.Error description is like this :

```
    Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection-
```

I think Tomcat can not connect to Database with this props.

My application.properties is :

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=IDDAA
spring.datasource.username=IDDAA
spring.datasource.password=awedrtgh0349
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=15
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=HikariConnectionPool
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2014Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

I tried to change application.properties but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing maximum-pool-size=10.

For example one time i used pgAdmin it take 25 places. Maybe you have something like that ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

It would also be nice to clarify what exactly you changed in app.properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).